# Selenium grid 4 download file

Tags: docker-compose, download, selenium-grid, selenium4

Im using the Dynamic grid selenium 4 and trying to retrieve downloaded file on mac
here is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-docker:latest
    volumes:
      - ./assets:/opt/selenium/assets
      - ./config.toml:/opt/bin/config.toml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./down:/home/seluser/files
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:latest
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
```

the issue is Im unable to find the downloaded file, it's being well downloaded in my test and appears in the bottom tab.
I have set up also the chrome prefs

```
chromePreferences.put("download.default_directory", PATH_TO_HOST_DIR);
```